# Why was this Android question closed as "primarily opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen, specific-audit

The question [Is it possible to use android module library in react-native project and also work for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57430494/2985643) was *"**closed** as primarily opinion-based"*:

> i already created android library in Android and i don't want to
>   re-create in react-native, Is it possible to reuse that library in
>   react-native and work for both and Android and IOS

The question is unusually short, but it received one answer which was accepted.

I was reviewing the Reopen Queue, and voted to reopen it, also adding this as a comment to the question:

```
Voting to reopen since this question was closed as "primarily opinion-based". The question is not asking for opinions at all; it is explicitly asking "Is it possible to reuse that library...?". Either it is possible or it isn't, but either way that is not a matter of opinion.
```

I was surprised to get this response after clicking the **Reopen** button:

```
STOP! Look and Listen.
This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This question has serious problems that must be fixed before it can be answered. If you're unable to fix these problems by Editing, you should Close such questions.

Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.
```

I have several questions arising:

1. Why is that question "*opinion based*" when it is explicitly asking whether something is possible? It still seems fine to me; the question is not seeking opinions, and I thought the accepted answer addressed the question. What is so problematic about that question that I am not understanding, and how is it seeking "opinion-based" answers?
2. Why is the system insistent that this particular question *"has serious problems"*? I have voted to **Leave closed** or **Reopen** hundreds of questions, and have never received *"You didn't pass"* as feedback before. Is there some automatic "red flag" against very concise questions like this one?
3. Is the question salvageable? If so, how?

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 18):

The biggest hang-up I can see with a question like this is that it's asking a fairly open-ended question.  Whether or not you can or cannot port something over from Android to React Native is a fairly boolean process, but the Devil is in the details.

Since we don't really know what *their* library does, we lack the ability to provide a more meaningful and more in-context answer.

So, the answer to the question that's being asked is, "it depends", which would make it a question which is too broad *or* opinionated, since we don't have any real way to define what success looks like from the perspective of the OP.

This definitely isn't a salvageable question.